# Evaluating three-variable expression in Prolog

Tags: prolog

Follow the Four-Step Abstract design process to define recursive rules to compute mathematical functions. You must indicate (use comments to code) which step is used. Note, a Prolog rule does not return a value. You need to use a parameter to hold the return value. You may NOT use the exponential operator `**` to compute the expressions.

Write a recursive rules `factbar(F, X, Y, N)` to compute `F = ((2*X + Y)^N)!` (factorial of expbar). The rule must call (use) the rule expbar that you designed..

Now for doing this operation `F = ((2*X + Y)^N)` I have already written my code but I do not know how to write factorial in Prolog:

```
expbar(R, X, Y, N) :-
   X > 0, Y > 0, N > 0,
   R is (2 * X + Y) ** N.
```

Although I have used ** in my program for exponent I did not know how to use the other way.

Comment: Please share what you've tried?

Comment: S.O. is not a free homework solution service. Work on the program yourself and come back with what you've done when you get stuck.

Comment: Use `^` in place of `**`.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what the "four step abstract design process" is and you haven't included that detail. As a result, you're going to instead get my two-step recursive function design process. Your predicate is right except you haven't defined `pow/3`, a function to compute powers. This is obviously the crux of your assignment. Let's do it.

Step one: identify your base cases. With arithmetic functions, the base case involves the arithmetic identity. For exponentiation, the identity is 1. In other words, X**1 = X. Write this down:

```
pow(X,1,X).
```

Because this is a function with two inputs and one result, we'll encode it as an arity-3 predicate. This fact simply says X to the 1st power is X.

Step two. Now consider the inductive case. If I have X**N, I can expand it to X * (X**(N-1)). By the definition of exponentiation and the induction rule, this completes the definition of the predicate. Encode it in Prolog syntax:

```
pow(X,N,Y) :-
  N > 1,
  succ(N0, N),
  pow(X, N0, Y0),
  Y is X * Y0, !.
```

This gives you a predicate for calculating exponents. If you replace your use of `**/2` in your `expbar/4` predicate, you fulfill the requirements of your assignment.